# Next.js weird render for first time render from server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have an issue with render from the server. On the first load of the page, the layout goes for a toss. However it is corrected on subsequent renders via navigating the pages. Surprisingly the weired layout also appears on a browser refresh. I have tested it with both Chrome and Microsoft Edge but same problem.
The app was created using standard boilerplate 'create-next-app' and then I just added a few of my pages. See screenshots below
[one with the weird screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr4vh.jpg)
 [and other showing correct render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQOKE.jpg)

Comment: have you figured out what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This actually an issue with CSS injection with SSR for material-ui. Check [examples here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/)